# from kivy.app import App error

Tags: python

I'v been comfigurating kivy on my computer for about a week, but I don't make it until now. I installed kivy and its dependency following the instruction on the official website. However, when I import kivy, there's terrible error.

Here's error when I imported it on command line:

```
>>>from kivy.app import App

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ricardo\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-10-23_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\clock.py", line 364, in <module>
     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\logger.py", line 291, in write
     s = self.buffer + s
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the error showed when I import it in an script:
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Ricardo.kivy\logs\kivy_16-10-23_1.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Python27/1.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "C:\Python27\lib\kivy\clock.py", line 364, in <module>
     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
```

I'm using Python2.7.12 on windows 10,I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Is it possible you installed the wrong version of kivy ? DLL load failed is usually happening when you install Python 2.6 package on a 2.7.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I've checked and didn't find there is a problem on the version of kivy.